How to configure AppDomain properly?
I want avoid dependency conflicts between plugins for my .NET Framework 4.8 application.
My research led me to separate AppDomains for each plugin.
I found this example and I think I understand the code.
https://github.com/rciworks/RCi.Tutorials.Advanced (Tutorial 5)
There is an exteral assembly which shall be loaded in a separate AppDomain.
The following lines create a new Appdomain and create an instance of SomeClass in that new domain.
 AppDomainExternalLib = AppDomain.CreateDomain("AppDomainExternalLib");

  var typeSomeClass = typeof(SomeClass).FullName ?? throw new NullReferenceException();
  SomeClass = (SomeClass)AppDomainExternalLib.
                   CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeSomeClass);

SomeClass inherits MarshalByRefObject and serves as a proxy between both AppDomains.
In the example it loads an external assembly inside the new AppDomain and relays functions calls into that AppDomain.
My problem:
In opposite to the example above, the assemblies I want to load have dependencies and whatever I try using ResolveEventHandlers, PrivateBinPath, ApplicationPath,... I always run into exceptions because dependencies could not be loaded.
So given a folder structure like:
bin\myapp.exe
bin\lib\myappAPI.dll
bin\Plugins\PluginA\pluginA.dll
bin\Plugins\PluginA\References\someotherlib.dll

My question
How would I properly load pluginA.dll, that refers to myappAPI.dll and someotherlib.dll ,in its own AppDomain? How do I setup the assembly search?
